# Ultrasonic sensor which can access raw echo signal

Tags: arduino-ultra-sonic

I want to conduct an experiment which needs cheap Waterproof Ultrasonic sensor with the ability of accessing raw echo signal. However, perhaps I can't find such product in the market.
Currently, the sensor like JSN-SR04T is very popular, but it can only access the transmitting time of echo. The raw signal has been processed and I CAN'T get it.

Seems most companies just want to provide sensor with ranging ability not others, but my project highly rely on getting the raw data.
For your information, I know that Sonar may match my expectation, and I have already bought one. But the price is too expensive and I don't need such good one.

So I wonder if you guys know some sensor can achieve it? The worst case I have to hack the current circuit, it will cost too much unmeaningful time.

Edit:
Some company do provide solution, which is just have an analog output of the  circuit. And I will update the performance later.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean to post this in Electrical Engineering or some other SE site?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.